# best practice nginx Load balancer snippet annotation

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, load-balancing, nginx-ingress, code-snippets

I want to run the Load balancer and modified the configuration with snippet annotation.

`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet:`
[here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#configuration-snippet)

which will divide the request equally. I have 4 nodes and I will give 100.000 requests to my nodes, each node will get 25.000 requests. however, I should care about the latency, success rate and also hardware consuming resources. what should I be concerned about in writing my snippet code?

Comment: Do you need snippet code for equal distribution?

Comment: yes  i do need equal distribution while consider about the latency and resources

Comment: The best practice at meta level is not to use snippets as it's disabled [by default](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/advanced-configuration-with-snippets/#summary-of-snippets) due to a list of [disadvantages](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/advanced-configuration-with-snippets/#disadvantages-of-using-snippets) 

The best practice on using snippets is to try and minimize the impact from these disadvantages.

Comment: do you have any suggestions on what could I do to improve the performance of Load Balancer? if snippet is not right solution.

Comment: Check the [Tips for peak load balancing performance](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/three-tips-for-peak-cloud-load-balancing-performance) and [Optimizing application latency with load balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/tutorials/optimize-app-latency). Let me know if these docs helps

Comment: do you think it relates to my machine? because I don't use any cloud provider only Bare-Metal